# Unable to automount the hard-disk drive on startup?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, automount

I have 500 GB HardDisk and below are my partitions:

- 500MB - /boot
- 50GB - /
- 4800MB - swap
- 440GB - Perosnal Drive

I keep all my data in Personal Drive including Wallpapers, Music, Movies, Study Materials, Software Packages, Office works, etc..

I have set the desktop wallpaper from Personal Drive and Rhythmbox to use Personal Drive ->Music Folder to scan music files.

When I start Ubuntu 14.04, I cannot play the songs in Rhythmbox. I have to mount the Personal Drive everytime and then only I can play the songs.

Same is the issue with wallpaper, it falls back to default wallpaper and again I have to mount it and set the wallpaper again.

Please find the attached screenshot of the Disk App for Personal Drive.[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your mount into fstab. Since you haven't provided any useful info about partitions this is how you do it in a general way.

1. mount manually
2. cat /etc/mtab | grep 'name of Perosnal Drive partition'
3. Output from previous command should be one line, something like this `/dev/sdb2 /media/yourname/partitionname ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2 0 0`
4. append that line to /etc/fstab while being root (with sudo)
5. reboot to test if it'll mount

Comment: What info is required?

Comment: Mount it manually and post this here: `sudo cat /etc/mtab`

Comment: Ok will definetly try...

Comment: I have edited my question - added a screenshot of Disks App of Personal Drive. Please assist

Comment: Please post output of `sudo cat /etc/mtab` while your partition is mounted.

Comment: /dev/sda3 /media/techsavy/Perosnal ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2 0 0

Comment: Great, now add that line to the end of /etc/fstab file (see my post for instructions), remove that entry for Disk App and reboot to test.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the screenshot provided, actually you should slide the "Automatic Mount Options" switch to "OFF". The "Mount at startup" and "Show in user interface" will become accessible (ensure they remain ticked), then click the OK button. The said partition should then automatically mount itself on your next reboot. To easily identify the partition you can change its "Mount Point" name to something recognizable, for example: "/mnt/PersonalDrive"; avoid spaces and use underscore if you must, like "/mnt/Personal_Drive".

Comment: I tried, but it gave me error at boot time

Comment: Paste the error message here please.